# emacs auto escape of '\' when cut and pasting regexps

Tags: regex, emacs

If I run a regexp I-search and try and cut and paste in a regexp I've prepared earlier, emacs trys to be helpful and auto escape any '\' chars

e.g. if I paste in:

```
[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}
```

It turns it into:

```
\[0-9]\\{2\\}/\[0-9]\\{2\\}
```

Its very annoying - how can I turn it off?

Comment: Which operating system? Does it happen when you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: i'm using emacs 24.3.1 on ubuntu 14.04 - behaves the same in emacs -Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the assumption here is that you're more likely to be pasting in a literal string to be found than a pre-made regexp.

There is nothing you can do to turn it off, but if you hit <kbd>M-e</kbd> and then yank, it works as expected.

Comment: That works like a charm - I note from hitting C-h c M-e that runs the command prolog-end-of-clause - what is this doing to make it work?

Comment: Once isearch starts a different keymap is used.  Press C-h c M-e from within isearch to see the command invoked.